# Accessing array from pointer gives changing, wrong values

Tags: c, pointers, serial-port, arduino

I am trying to send an array on my Arduino over serial to my computer. However, whenever I receive the array, it contains apparently random and sometimes changing data second-by-second. This makes me suspect that I have referenced the pointer incorrectly, but I can't find a problem with my syntax.

The array is generated by buildreport(), which returns a boolean* to the first element in the array. That is taken up by loop(), which writes it over the serial line.

```
//read pins
boolean report[NUM_BUTTONS] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; //I set this to all zeroes for testing and brevity
boolean* x = &report[0];
return x;
```

And loop()

```
//if I don't read the serial, it will always be 
//available and execute forever.

if(Serial.available() != 0){ 
 incoming = Serial.read();
 boolean* reports = buildreport();
 //reports should now be the first element of the array
 for(int i=0;i<NUM_BUTTONS;i++){
   boolean x = *(reports+i);
   //x is set to value at reports[0] plus i

   Serial.write(x);

 } 
 Serial.write(0x0d); //carriage return
 Serial.write(0x0a); //line feed
}
```

Every time I ask for the array by sending, well, anything down the serial line, I get 9 bytes that are not one or zero. Sometimes the first byte will change.

Comment: Please provide a complete listing of your Arduino sketch.  Remember, sketchs are NOT C code, so many C rules don't apply.  Also, as a quick check does your sketch start the serial line w/same parameters as your PC?

Comment: @JackCColeman Huh what? Sketches **are** C (or C++, it depends) code.

Comment: A sketch is a portion of a larger program that is NOT visible to the programmer.

Comment: @JackCColeman That larger program is `int main() { setup(); while (1) loop(); }`. Still, it **is** C.

Comment: @H2CO3 There are constants like HIGH LOW and other constructs that imply a more complicated "dispatcher".  To quote their web page, "the Arduino Language is based on C/C++"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `report` is an array of automatic storage duration, it's destroyed when the function returns. Using it (through `x`, the pointer to its first element) invokes undefined behavior.

If you want a function to create an array, then you have to use dynamic memory allocation (accompilshed by `malloc()` and its friends) or pass in the array as the function's argument and let the function fill it with the appropriate values.

Comment: Not sure advice to use malloc() in a function and returning that pointer is good advice for someone just beginning to understand life cycles.  I don't see that ending well.

Comment: I'll stick with creating the array in loop() and passing it in. Thanks for the help!